# How to add en-dash and em-dash in a regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want to add client side regex validation to inlcude en-dash(–) and em-dash(—)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NameRegExValidator" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\d.,!&/\(\)#\$?£àÀâÂäÄáÁéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòÒôÔöÖùÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñ€\|%\^\*@`~\+;:\-'\s\\&quot;]+" ErrorMessage="Illegal Characters" ControlToValidate="Name" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a .net expert, but couldn't you just put the characters in the class?
Or put the codepoint in the class, or thier char references (xhtml/xml).

```
en dash – U+2013 &ndash; &#x2013; or &#8211;  
em dash — U+2014 &mdash; &#x2014; or &#8212;   

[a-zA-Z\d.,!&/\(\)#\$?£àÀâÂäÄáÁéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòÒôÔöÖùÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñ€\|%\^\*@`~\+;:\-'\s\\&quot;&#x2013;&#x2014;]+
```

[a-zA-Z\d.,!&/()#\$?£àÀâÂäÄáÁéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòÒôÔöÖùÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñ€\|%\^*@`~+;:-'\s\"–—]+

Comment: Try to validate the codepoints alone in the class. Does .Net regex have a special Unicode flag mode? I'm not sure about the syntax for .net codepoints. It might be \u{2013} for example. In Perl its \x{2013}. Sorry couldn't be more help. Also, move the ascii dash '-' to the far right in the character class.